# Injecting Mocks for testing with Dagger 2.11 Android

Tags: android, testing, dagger-2

I am using dagger 2.11 for an MVP app. Naturally, I want to write unit tests for my application, but I have run into some problems. I have an activity that has a presenter. When testing that activity I want to inject a mock presenter so I can verify that certain methods are called. The presenter is injected via Dagger 2.11 in the activity. My dagger setup is exactly the same as is described in these two articles:

https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe
https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-2-4af05fd783d0

I use the annotations described in the latter, meaning I use the @ContributesAndroidInjector in a BuildActivity file instead of separate subcomponents.

My question is: How would I go about injecting the mock of the presenter?

Comment: Your presenter has a dependency on view, right?

Comment: Yes, the view is also injected into the presenter.